# Impact of decommission TLS 1.0 TLS 1.1 on iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, security, mobile, tls1.2

I am checking the impact on iOS app upon decommission of TLS 1.0/TLS 1.1 & commission TLS 1.2 on server side.

Before adding support for TLS 1.2 on server side, I am assuming "URLSessionConfiguration.default.tlsMinimumSupportedProtocol = SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol12"; is the only way we can test its impact on iOS app(both URLSession/NSURLConnection & WKWebView/UIWebView). Could you please confirm the same. Also let me know if there is another way to do that.

After adding support for only TLS 1.2(removing TLS1.0 & TLS1.1) on server side(www.nist.gov, https://github.com, https://fancyssl.hboeck.de) I tried to load the page in WKWebView by setting "URLSessionConfiguration.default.tlsMaximumSupportedProtocol = SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol11" but seems like it works. My expectation was it should not work. (Tried it on iOS 8 Simulator with iOS 11.2)

Posted same question [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/316114#316114) too

Answer (score 2):

I found answer to my own questions in [apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67984)